# Use Python to split text file into chunks by unique character and a blank line at the end

Tags: python, text, file-io

Given a text input file, I want to split it into chunks to contain every line that begins with 'c' with a blank space between each chunk. I have successfully isolated every 'c' line, but how to keep or add a blank line between chunks is eluding me.

**Here is the infile:**

c70  Title -1
c
c
c
c
c
c   heading1 heading2   heading3     heading4
data data data data

c80  Title -2
c
c
c
c
c
c   heading1 heading2   heading3     heading4
data data data data

c90  Title -3
c
c
c
c
c
c   heading1 heading2   heading3     heading4
data data data data

**This is my code:**

> ```
> for line in infile:
>     if not line.lstrip().startswith('c'):
>         copy = True
>         continue
>     elif line == '\n':
>         copy = True
>         continue
>     elif copy:
>         outfile.write(line)
> ```

**This is my outfile:**

c70  Title -1
c
c
c
c
c
c   heading1 heading2   heading3     heading4
c80  Title -2
c
c
c
c
c
c   heading1 heading2   heading3     heading4
c90  Title -3
c
c
c
c
c
c   heading1 heading2   heading3     heading4

**This is my desired outfile:**

c70  Title -1
c
c
c
c
c
c   heading1 heading2   heading3     heading4

c80  Title -2
c
c
c
c
c
c   heading1 heading2   heading3     heading4

c90  Title -3
c
c
c
c
c
c   heading1 heading2   heading3     heading4

The only difference between my current outfile and my desired outfile is to to keep the existing blank line or add a blank line between chunks.

Comment: I think the issue is that your programming goal isn't clear enough. How do you define a chunk? Does every empty line count as the end of a chunk? Answering these questions will help you figure out exactly what you want and what test cases to check for.

Comment: You have got it, @wxz 

A chunk is started by 'c' and ends with a blank line. every empty line counts as the end of a chunk. and every 'c70', 'c80', 'c90', etc. counts as a beginning

Comment: Not to be rude, are you familiar with if-else logic in programming? Here are a couple hints to help get you thinking in the right direction: As soon as your input satisfies an if or elif statement, no other elif/else statement will be executed for that iteration. Also, since this is such a small program, putting print statements in your if blocks can help you visually see what is executing for every line.

Comment: hi @wxz this is not rude at all. I am a beginner and therefore not familiar with if/else statements in programming. Thanks for the tips and I will do the print statements as you suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should do what you are hoping for:

```
for line in infile:
    if line.lstrip().startswith("c") or line == "\n":
        outfile.write(line)
```

You can scan each line, and check if it starts with a `c` or if it is a newline, and only write those to the output file.